# jQuery anonymous vs named function syntax

Tags: jquery, function, anonymous, named

This code works to fade and loop an audio element when a button is pressed:

```
$("#loop").click(function(){
    var tone = document.getElementById("testTone");
    tone.play();
    $("#testTone").animate({volume: 0}, 1900);
    setInterval(function(){
        tone.currentTime = 0;
        tone.volume = 1;
        tone.play();
        $("#testTone").animate({volume: 0}, 1900);
    },2000)
});
```

However, when I name the function, it calls immediately on page load, without pressing the button.

```
function loopAudio(target){
    var tone = document.getElementById(target);
    tone.play();
    $("#"+target).animate({volume: 0}, 1900);
    setInterval(function(){
        tone.currentTime = 0;
        tone.volume = 1;
        tone.play();
        $("#"+target).animate({volume: 0}, 1900);
    },2000)
};
$("#loop").click(loopAudio("testTone"));
```

Why? And what is the right way to call this named function?

EDIT:
Since passing the parameter calls the function, what is a good workaround strategy to pass in a parameter?

Comment: because... you called it. If it returned a function that then did the stuff, then it would work as you expected it to.

Comment: because you are calling it you need your click assignment to be `$("#loop").click(loopAudio);`  I suggest you place an attribute on the `#loop` element to specify the tone instead of using an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("#loop").click(function(){
  loopAudio("testTone");
});
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!